# Response of a service is null in another service in Angujar JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a service from a $resource, because the request needs authentication, I'm sending an Authorization header.

So I have 2 services:

- authService
- userInforService

authService:

```
var ouveerApiServices = angular.module('ouveerServices.api', []);
ouveerApiServices.factory('authService', ['$http', '$rootScope', 'localStorageService', 'apiService',
    function($http, $rootScope, localStorageService, apiService){

        return {
            isLogged : function(){
                return (localStorageService.get('accessToken')) ? true : false;
            },
            logIn : function(email, password){

                var dataQuery = $.param({ 
                    grant_type: "password", 
                    username    : email,
                    password    : password
                });

                return $http({
                    url: $rootScope.apiURL + 'Auth', 
                    method: 'POST',
                    data : dataQuery,
                    withcredentials : true,
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type'    : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }
                });
            },
            logOut : function(){
                return apiService.post({ url: 'api/Account/Logout' });
            },
            getAccessToken : function(){
                return localStorageService.get('accessToken');
            }
        } //return
    } //function
]);
```

And the userInfoService:

```
var ouveerUserServices = angular.module('ouveerServices.user', []);

//user related queries
ouveerApiServices.factory('userInfoService', ['$resource', '$rootScope', 'localStorageService', 'authService',
    function($resource, $rootScope, localStorageService, authService){
        return $resource($rootScope.apiURL + 'api/users/:userId', { userId : '@id' }, {
            update :  { 
                method: 'PUT',
                isArray : false
            },
            account : {
                method : 'GET',
                isArray : false,
                url: $rootScope.apiURL + 'api/Account/UserInfo',
                headers : {
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + authService.getAccessToken()
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

The problems is at the time I call (in a controller):

```
$scope.signIn = function(){
    $scope.messages = [];
    console.log($scope.user.semail);
    if($scope.user.semail && $scope.user.spassword){
        authService.logIn($scope.user.semail, $scope.user.spassword).success(function(data){

            localStorageService.add('accessToken', data.access_token);

            console.log(authService.getAccessToken());

            //setting userID in localstorage
            userInfoService.account(function(){

                localStorageService.add('userId', userData.userId); 
                $location.path('/library');
            });

        }).error(function(){
            $scope.status = 'error';
            $scope.messages[0] = ['Review the fields please, something is wrong...'];
        });

    } else {
        $scope.status = 'error';
        $scope.messages[0] = ['Type your email and password.'];
    }
}
```

It returns null, but as you note I'm dumping the var just before the call of userInfoService and it response the Auth code, anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you **initialize** the account property in following way:

```
account : {
    method : 'GET',
    isArray : false,
    url: $rootScope.apiURL + 'api/Account/UserInfo',
    headers : {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + authService.getAccessToken()
    }
}
```

This code (including `authService.getAccessToken()`) is run upon the *creation* of the service, i.e long before the code in the controller. Hence, `authService.getAccessToken()` is resolved, and at that point in time it is null.

To put another way, when you try to actually use the header in the account resource, it is just a string, created long ago.